# Apache Camel triggering a route on more than one file

Tags: java, apache-camel

We have several camel routes configured in our application, but each route triggers whenever a single file is dropped into a directory.
One of these routes, route A, polls for two files and moves then to /done.
I need to create a route B which will trigger (to move another file elsewhere) only when both files are in the /done for route A. 
it's not immediately clear from the on-line documentation how to do this.

Comment: Could you provide what you've done so far?

Comment: Maybe the [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) component is what you are looking for?

Comment: Aggregator will merge two files, I think, whereas I need to trigger a route only when two specific files are in a directory.  I've got the two routes, both of which are working in the sense that they move files. Route A will move two files and copy them to it's done dir. Route B will be triggered by a file deposited in route A's done dir. I need route B to wait until both files have been moved to done by A.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In the end, I used an extension of the DefaultPollingConsumerPollStrategy on my route B. So, in the begin method I return true only if both files moved by Route A are present in the "done" folder. This has the effect of route B not moving its file until that condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an event driven design that requires state (2 files need to be moved)

1. routeA moves fileX.. when completed.. send an event to a topic / queue
2. routeB moves fileY.. when completed.. send an event to a topic / queue

Depending on how long and how often this needs to occur and whether or not you require a way to correlate A & B-- you need design your reliability accordingly.

3a. routeC listens to topic / queue and you could use an aggregator to wait for both

-- or --

3b. routeC listens to topic and stores the data in a db / temp store that A occurred.. and then B occurred.

4. routeD polls to find when A & B have been completed.. then uses a pollingConsumer to begin processing File C.

[Camel Polling Consumer][1]http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html